# Is there a reason for virtual env running OK inside visual studio but not through Powershell?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

There is something going on that im not being able to solve.
I have a Python project running inside visual studio 2019. In there I created a virtual env with all my required libraries.
I organized the project by folders and the folder in question has an **init**.py file.

[Folder Organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw2NZ.png)

I have one of the .py files inside the folder that imports other functions from the adjecent files. Everything works fine in visual studio. If i run "Start without debugging" on that file. It open up a command prompt on windows and the code starts running in the background flawlessly.

Now, I want to be able to call that process from windows after it is developed, and so, I check where Visual Studio installed the virtual environment so that I can run the script with that version. And I do just that:

C:......_First_Project_environment\Scripts\python.exe C:..._First_Project...... .py

And I get and error:
  File "C:..._First_Project...... .py", line 3, in 
    import x.y as crawler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'y'

But this is not true... there is a module named 'y', because the code runs OK inside visual studio or when i tell it to run from there.

Line 3 reads as
import x.y

and x is the name of the folder, y is the name of the file..

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is powershell using the same python installation as VS?

Comment: Did you actually switch to the virtual environment using source command?

Comment: Yes. That instance of Python that I am calling on the Powershell is the same .exe that has the virutal env that VS is using. I checked to see the installed packages. Same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution myself. Sorry.

I was missing the reference to the folder where the module lives on sys.path

Added a .pth file on the lib/site-packages folder with the path to the module folder.

Worked like a charm.

Regards.